# Does Tolle fidem, culpam dare convey the correct meaning?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I've looked up the translation of "Take Credit, Assign Blame" (a pseudo-motto for managers) and I got '*Sume fidem, culpam dare*', and then later I found '*Tolle fidem, culpam dare*'.

Does this faux-motto convey the attitude of someone who takes credit for successes and assigns blame to underlings when things fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wouldn't be very idiomatic. In fact, *sume fidem* and *tolle fidem* could both mean "abolish trust." I wouldn't go that route.

A major mistake new learners of Latin (and any foreign language) make is to go for a one-to-one translation. Languages however have their own traditions and idiomatic expressions. For these expressions, I'd offer the following:

> Te lauda aliosque culpa.
>
> Praise yourself and blame others.

Not only is it more idiomatic, but in Latin *laus* and *culpa* are often seen as antonyms. Horace, for example, writes:

> Laudatur ab his, culpatur ab illis.
>
> He is praised by some, condemned by others.

To be a more ancient aphorism, you'd probably even see it filled out a bit, though that wouldn't be necessary for a modern motto. Regardless, it could look something like this:

> Vincens te lauda; victus alios culpa.
>
> In conquering praise yourself; but, when conquered, blame others.

I just can't see Caesar saying that, though.

Comment: I wonder if *te ipsum* (or maybe *te ipse*) would be more idiomatic than just *te*? (Also I feel the imperatives might be better placed first, but that's very debatable.)

Comment: @TKR There's no real rule on placement - there are examples of both (cf. Cicero's *iustitiam cole et pietatem*). To my ears, *lauda te* sounds too close to *laudate*, so I inverted them, but very little thought was otherwise given to the order.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another suggestion that reworks your sentence a bit:

> Serva lauream; divide culpam.

This literally means:

> Keep the [victor's] garland; divide the blame.

Answer (score 4):

A suggestion modelled from Cic.Philipp. II. 11,

*Laudes accipe sed onera alios*.

Comment: A good parallel, but I think it's a pretty different idea: "accept the praise, divide the work" (not the "blame")

Comment: Is it possible that you have misread _onera_ as _opera_? Colloquially, 'Take the praise, but let others carry the can'.